# Adding Page in PageAdapter

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-viewpager, adapter, pager

I have the following Problem. I have a `PagerAdapter` with should load the content of the pages(Pictures) dynamically in the background...first the viewpager is loaded with a single page. then an asynctask gets for a specific UserID all URLs from the Pictures the user have...then the PagerAdapter should create as much Default pages as Pictures are going to load..and finally the Pictures should load via an asynctask..

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
String[] urls;
ArrayList<Bitmap> pics = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
GalleryPagerAdapter mAdapter = new GalleryPagerAdapter(this, urls, pics);

public void savePicUrls(String result){
    String[] urls = result.toString().split(",");

    for(int i=0; i<urls.length; i++){

// This asyncTask starts in his onPostExecute method, the method "savePic" in the MainActivity with a single Bitmap
        List_getImage test = new List_getImage(urls[i], this);
        test.execute();
    }
}

public void savePic(Bitmap result){
    pics.add(result);
    //mAdapter = new GalleryPagerAdapter(this, urls, pics);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();    
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_layout_activity);
    GalleryPagerAdapter adapter = new GalleryPagerAdapter(this, urls, pics);
    ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

PagerAdapter:

```
public class GalleryPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
String USID = "2";
int count=1;
String url="http://193.171.131.105/prein/bluepeople/SucheFotos_PREIN.php";
MainActivity actRef;
String[] urls;
ArrayList<Bitmap> pics;

public GalleryPagerAdapter(MainActivity actRef, String[] urls, ArrayList<Bitmap> pics) {
    this.actRef = actRef;
    this.urls = urls;
    this.pics = pics;
}

public void setCount(int PageCount){
    count = count + PageCount;
    System.out.println(count);
}

public int getCount() {
    return pics.size() + 1;
}

public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int pos) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View page = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, null);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) page.findViewById(R.id.up_pub_iv_viewpager);
    if(pos == 0){
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("USID", USID));

// This asyncTask starts in his onPostExecute method, the method "savePicUrls" in the     MainActivity with a String with all the URLs of the pictures
        UserProfilePub_getImageUrl upp_getImageUrls = new UserProfilePub_getImageUrl(nameValuePair, url, actRef, iv);
        upp_getImageUrls.execute();

    if(pics.size() != 0){
        iv.setImageBitmap(pics.get(pos));
    }

    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(page, 0);
    return page;


}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
    ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}
}
```

I think everything should work correctly...but it doesnt..the app crashes with a "IllegalStateException...the Pagerscontent get changed without calling .notifyDataSetChanged" 
but I exactly do this in the "savePic" method...i rly dont know where my mistake is...at least are there any other ways to get an viewpager which loads Pictures dynamically in the Background with adding Default pages before?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

where do you call savePic()?

If you call it from doInBackground() of the ASyncTask this might be the problem. The error message is a little weird, but I think I saw this message when an adapter was changed from a non-UI- thread.

If this is the case, use publishProgress() in doInBackground() and call savePic in the AsyncTask's onProgressUpdate().
(Or collect all pics in doInbackground and handle the adding in onPostExecute)

If this is not the case, let me know where you call savePic

Comment: the savePic gets called in the onPostExecute method of the asynctask, in his doInBackground method, the Pictures get loaded from their URLs..
and the savePic method gets called, and also the pics get added correctly

Comment: ok, maybe the stacktrace would help..where exactly is the exception thrown?
Also (I don't know whether it might have something to do with your problem), I think it's not a  good idea to do all that stuff in onInstantiateItem. This is called every time a page becomes visible. You should create the views in getView(). These will be recycled and only created if needed.
And why don't you load urls and images in one async task?

Comment: to be honest..i dont rly get where the exception gets thrown exactly..after the pics get added to the Array and the .notifyDataSetChanged method gets called...the Counter from getCount in the Adapter is 4..thats right...but still there are coming up few Problems and Ends with the exception mentioned above...

Comment: moreover..i had another way to solve what i want...first i worked with Fragments..this also worked fine, till i couldnt solve the Problem, that the Pictures doesnt get refreshed automatically..now im trying this way..and the reason why i'm not loading both together(what will be much easier on the other hand) is, that i want those Default pages without Pictures, that you see they are loading..and when the loading Task is finished, the Pictures should be shown...i want it for a "better usability"